# Visual Studio project configuration

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, dll, deployment, solution

I have a VisualStudio (2015 in case it matters) solution which has a C++ project compiled as a DLL, and that DLL is then used via DllImport in a C# Windows Forms project that is my executable. Let's call this executable **ExeA**. Because this **ExeA** needs my DLL in the same directory as the build location for **ExeA.exe**, and because I build for multiple platforms, in both Debug and Release flavors, configured the C++ project settings to have

```
<OutDir>$(SolutionDir)ExeA\bin\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\</OutDir>
```

This makes sure that whichever way I build my executable project, the DLL is always delivered to the correct folder. However, this hard-codes **ExeA** name into the C++ project settings.

I am now adding a secondary C# executable project, let's call it **ExeB**, which must also use this DLL. Ideally, I would modify my C++ project settings to pick up the name of the target executable project from some Visual Studio variable. I looked [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx), but could not find a variable that represents the name of the project within a solution which is currently set as the "executable" project. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: If you are talking about StartUp Project, then it's an instruction to the debugger, not to the build. Changing startup project doesn't cause a rebuild. In fact, you can set up multiple startup projects: right-click the solution node, select "Set StartUp Projects..." (note plural).

Comment: What I am trying to do is related to "Set Startup Project" in a sense that I need a compile time scheme using Visual Studio variables to determine the path to where the final EXE of whichever "startup project" is selected will reside.

Comment: Like I said, you can't. First, there may be more than one startup projects: both your EXEs may be designated as such. Second, the startup project at the time you build may not be the same as startup project at the time you run. There's even a "Current selection" option - the startup project is whatever project happens to be selected in the Solution Explorer at the time you press F5. For all these reasons, a notion of a startup project is not exposed to the build process; it would make no sense to do so.